# How to put all buttons in flowlayoutpanel to array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, button, flowlayoutpanel

I have a code in `vb.net` to select all buttons in form within `flowlayoutpanel`, but it returns zero.

I think problem is with flowlayoutpanel.

```
Dim alphabetButtons() As Button
alphabetButtons = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button).Except(New Button() {Button1}).ToArray
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you'll probably have add a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a code in vb.net to select all buttons in form within **flowlayoutpanel**, but it returns zero. ... Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Yes.  You're telling the **Form** to return all Controls of Type Button:

```
Dim alphabetButtons() As Button
alphabetButtons = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button).Except(New Button() {Button1}).ToArray
```

You need to ask the **FlowLayoutPanel** this question.

Change `Me` to the name of your FlowLayoutPanel, such as `FlowLayoutPanel1` in the "fixed" code below:

```
Dim alphabetButtons() As Button
alphabetButtons = FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType(Of Button).Except(New Button() {Button1}).ToArray
```

The `Controls()` collection only returns controls that are **directly** contained by that container.  Each container has its own collection of child controls...